# Android Service application error - no launcher activity

Tags: android, service

I created a service application without any GUI...infact take help of other applications available on this website...but when i try to run it on my Emulator (2.3.3), I keep on getting error:

**2012-02-13 17:36:56 - RUN_SERVICE] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-02-13 17:36:56 - RUN_SERVICE] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!**

After it installs properly, but i dont see my service running...i tried adding toast messages, but I am not receving that as well...i didnt try it on real device yet...as I didnt have any phone with this android version 2.3.3. I am using jre6

Comment: Can you post your manifest code?

Answer (score 2):

As your applicatinon does not have any GUI.

You must start the Service from at least one activivity that may be lanucher acitivity by using

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER>
```

So that your Service need to start when the app is installed or Run.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined the activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file....

Answer (score 0):

I think you mentioned this in your manifest `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER>`. if yes then remove this